# Export a typescript function or a typescript const reference to a function?

Tags: typescript

I'm new to typescript and I am questioning a pattern in the codebase I inherited:

```
export const registerTubesReducer = handleTubeActions

function handleTubeActions(previousState: ITubes, action: TubeAction): ITubes {
```

versus

```
export function registerTubesReducer(previousState: ITubes, action: TubeAction): ITubes {
```

Is there any reason other than style to prefer export const over the plain function export?

Comment: I don't think so.  See if anyone else has anything to add.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch)

Comment: function & arrow functions treat "this" differently. If you are aware of that then not much to add. I would say the first snipped is bad though because it uses "handleTubeActions" before it is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no major difference in this case. Although the first version can be simplified to

```
export const registerTubesReducer = (previousState: ITubes, action: TubeAction): ITubes => { ... }
```

---

Differences to be aware of between arrow and regular functions.

1) Arrow functions have a lexically bound `this` which does not change depending on how you invoke the function

2) Arrow functions are not hoisted as they are just variable declarations with a function value. You will not be able to use the function until it is defined or else you will be calling and `undefined` variable

```
arrowAdd(1, 2) // arrowAdd will be undefined here
functionAdd(1,2) // All good since function declarations are hoisted

const arrowAdd = (a: number, b: number) => a + b

function functionAdd(a: number, b:number) {
  return a + b
}
```

3) Arrow functions allow you to omit the extra curly braces if you only want to return a value

There is a canonical answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch) for more details about the differences between arrow and regular functions